# Laravel 5 - DB::table in controller is not returning the related objects

Tags: laravel

I have this code in my controller:

```
        $messages = DB::table('kidmessages')
                ->whereIn('kid_id', function($query) {
                    $query->select(DB::raw('id'))
                    ->from('kids')
                    ->whereRaw('kids.place_id = ' . User::find(Auth::id())->place->id);
                })
                ->orderBy(Input::get('orderBy', 'created_at'), 'desc')
                ->get();
```

And it's returning an array with the data I need, however if I try this: (state and kidmessage is a 1-to-many relationship)

```
dd($messages->get(0)->state);
```

I get a `Undefined property: stdClass::$state`

But if I change it to:

```
    dd($messages->get(0)->state_id);
```

I get the id(integer) of the state.

Doing a `$messages = Kidmessages::all();` does return the state object with no `Undefined property: stdClass::$state` error.

Makes me realize that DB::table doesn't return the objects are related.

Any clue how can I make DB::table return all the objects?

PD. That query I got it from this:

```
select * from kidmessages where kid_id in(select id from kids where
place_id = (select place_id from users where id=10)) order by created_at desc;
```

If there is a way I can replicate that SQL query without using DB::table, that may help.

Answer (score 0):

Try this join query

```
 $messages  = DB::table('kidmessages')
            ->join('kids', 'kids.id', '=', 'kidmessages.kid_id')
            ->join('users', 'users.place_id', '=', 'kids.place_id')
            ->where('users.id', 10)  
            ->orderBy('kidmessages.created_at', 'desc')
            ->get();
```

Comment: I still got the same problem however that query does the same thing I did with the other one but prettier, just wow!!, nice one!

Comment: I think one more join is required for state. State name in which table?

Comment: Table: "states"

Comment: Something like this       ->join('place', 'place.id', '=', 'users.place_id')
            ->join('states', 'states.id', '=', 'place.state_id')

Comment: I had this:
$messages = DB::table('kidmessages')
                    ->join('kids', 'kids.id', '=', 'kidmessages.kid_id')
                    ->join('users', 'users.place_id', '=', 'kids.place_id')
                    ->join('places', 'places.id', '=', 'users.place_id')
                    ->join('states', 'states.id', '=', 'kidmessages.state_id')
                    ->where('users.id', 10)
                    ->orderBy('kidmessages.created_at', 'desc')
                    ->get();
            
            dd($messages->get(0)->state->name);

still same error

Comment: I'll approach the requirement in a different way, thanks anyways for the help. :)

Comment: Just dd($messages[0]->state)

Comment: dd($messages[0]->state);
got the same problem